# decoration in package explorer for main method in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to add an icon decoration for classes with main methods so it will be easy to find these classes in the tree?

This will help a lot as in some projects I have many classes with main method.

Thanks,
Guy

Comment: [The icons of classes that contain a main method are already decorated](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-12.htm?cp). In the _Package Explorer_ the main method decoration is visible in the class icon (one level below the file icon) at the bottom right. Unfortunately, an existing Git/SVN/etc. decoration at the same place hides the main method decoration.

Comment: you are right, it is the svn decoration that hides it. Thanks